# Oracle statement hanging

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a quite simple SQL statement which is executed on a Oracle 10g database. It moves some data from one schema to another:

```
CREATE TABLE TARGET.BIG_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM SOURCE.BIG_TABLE
WHERE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) IN (SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TARGET.HELP_TABLE);
```

There is a unique constraint in TARGET.HELP_TABLE for COLUMN1 and COLUMN2. In the SOURCE.BIG_TABLE there is only a combined primary key(COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5).

There is no problem with the statement itself since it was already executed several times while testing on a similar testing environment.

However, at the real environment this statement didn't had any I/O activity after about 3 hours. 8 hours later we aborted the execution.

What can be the reason for this behaviour? And what can I do to get to the root of the problem? I definitely don't have a clue!

Comment: Is it being locked by an uncommitted transaction?

Comment: Theoretically, that's not possible. Before execution of the statement all processes that make transactions into the source schema are shut down. However, is there some possibility to get to know why the statement is hanging or why it is waiting?

Comment: The Query might be taking so much time. Did you check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` [result of your select query](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Explain_Plan) in the production environment

Comment: Approximately how many rows in HELP_TABLE? And in SOURCE.BIG_TABLE? How many of those rows do you expect to be selected? What happens if you just run the SELECT?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'proper' way to do it, but Toad has a tool that lets you see what's going on with the session.

Comment: The plans for the select on its own and the CTAS might be useful. How long does the select take on its own in production? What patch level of 10g are you on (in test and live)? If before 10.2.0.3 it might be worth looking at bug 4768040 or note 399077.1 in My Oracle Support, but hard to tell might what might be going on.

Comment: Could this be related to the storage media? Where are physically located both tables? On a physical hard-drive attached to the station? On a remote SAN? NAS? Same device for both tables ?

Comment: Maybe there is an index missing on HELP_TABLE?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get rid off nested loops in explain plan. Consider to rewrite query using inner join:

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash(a b) */
       a.* 
  FROM SOURCE.BIG_TABLE a
 inner join (SELECT distinct COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TARGET.HELP_TABLE) b
    on b.COLUMN1 = a.COLUMN1
   and b.COLUMN2 = a.COLUMN2;
```

Also consider to use `use_hash` hint. Indexes should not be used when you select ALL rows (except case when column1 and column2 from help_table could be returned with index fast full scan). Use `distinct` in inner query only if there are duplications.

Consider to add `parallel` hint.